# Azure Logic Apps and Microsoft Forms - Get field descriptors

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-forms

I have a Logic App that retrieves the responses submitted by the users through Microsoft Forms.

When I see the Logic App Run, I can see the descriptor for each field (MuleSoft, IoT & Integration, Encuesta de tecnologías, ...), for example:

[image]

But in the "Show raw outputs" I can't see those fields, I get an identifier (rcb6ccf0fc9e44f74b44fa2715fec4f27, ...):

[image]

How I can retrieve those descriptors??

Comment: I also have this question. Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @SteveLovell I gave the solution on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a '**Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**' action to get the details of the form.

[image]

The Site Address is: **https://forms.office.com**
The Method is: **GET**
The Uri is: /formapi/api/forms('')?select=id,title,questions&$expand=questions($expand=choices)

This returns a JSON with all the questions and for each question the ID, Title and more info about the question.

We can implement a loop through these questions and with each ID, extract the response from the Microsoft Forms:

```
foreach": "@body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['questions']"
```

And Compose the result:

```
"Compose": {
   "inputs": {
      "Id": "@{items('For_each')['id']}",
      "Name": "@items('For_each')['title']",
      "Value": "@{body('Get_response_details')[item()['id']]}"
   },
   "runAfter": {},
   "type": "Compose"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are field identifiers. You can retrieve them directly from the Dynamic content of `Get response details`.

[image]

Alternatively, you can build your own JSON body(in your case `Get response details`) from Compose connector.

Comment: But it's possible to get the field names also?

Comment: @felixmondelo You can directly view those names from the Dynamic content itself.

Comment: @felixmondelo In case you want to send a custom body you can build it. Please refer the attached image https://i.imgur.com/Wmu5D4k.png

Comment: The question is if there is the possibility to get dynamically the field names.

Comment: @felixmondelo, afaik you can't get the form names dynamically